Move custom domain from Azure App service to Azure Static Web App
Quick introduction:

I have Blazor Webassembly standalone app, hosted on Azure App service with custom domain and Azure provided SNI SSL, let's say clients.company.com (Azure app original URL - company-clients.azurewebsites.net)
To reduce cost it has been decided to change hosting to Azure Static Web App
Sequence of actions:


Create new Azure Static Web App (company-clients-static). Standard hosting plan
Deploy code (Azure generated static web app pipeline)
Site works perfectly with funny generated URL https://gentle-fox-039244h02.5.azurestaticapps.net
Remove custom domain from Azure App service
Add custom domain to Azure Static Web App
Stop Azure App service, just in case :)

After couple of hours, I tried to access clients.company.com and got "Unsecure connection" and ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. Details show that cert, used for this site, has wildcard *.azurewebsites.net. I expected Static Web App will get new Azure generated SNI SSL cert for custom domain and at least wildcard *.azurestaticapps.net and that after changing hosting from App service to static web app and moving custom domain to static web app, site will be accessible as https://clients.company.com, but is's not due to cert error
Does anybody have similar issue and have any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Step 3 and 5 should never happen this early as DNS changes can take several days to take effect. You should keep the old App Service instance online till no one is using it any more. It also takes a while for Azure to recreate certificates, so temporary certificate errors are acceptable.

Thanks for a quick response, so from your experience - how long will it take to recreate new cert for static app, days, week? And I'm not sure I can add the same custom domain to different Azure services

For root domains, certificate generation can take several minutes, but for subdomains much quicker. Make sure your DNS service was configured properly, or there can be extra delay.

Initially domain provider DNS had CNAME pointed to company-clients.azurewebsites.net, during the migration CNAME has been updated to gentle-fox-039244h02.5.azurestaticapps.net.

Problem solved. Issue was with slow propagation. With DNS provider for test environment it took less than 2h, but with productionDNS provider - over 30h.
Just be patient.
